# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: mysql, cron

```
mysqldump -u user -pPassword databasename | gzip > /home/sandra/backup/databasename-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz
```

this executes correctly in a shell, but when put into crontab it generates error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: stupid question here: does your password have a '(' in it?

Comment: nope only letters and numbers, i did copy paste the text from notepad++ into the shell though, could that add some unexpected things?

Comment: Try to replace the $(date...) with the back ticks form `date...`. It may happen that the user shell is different from the shell used by cron or by the script itself.

Comment: that changed the error : /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Comment: solved by escaping % with \